# how to extract selected hyperparameter from hyperopt hp.choice?

Tags: python, hyperparameters, catboost, hyperopt

I'm using `hyperopt` to find the optimal hyperparameters to a `catboost` regressor.
I'm following this [guide](https://towardsdatascience.com/an-example-of-hyperparameter-optimization-on-xgboost-lightgbm-and-catboost-using-hyperopt-12bc41a271e).
the relevant part is:

```py
ctb_reg_params = {
    'learning_rate':     hp.choice('learning_rate',     np.arange(0.05, 0.31, 0.05)),
}
ctb_fit_params = {
    'verbose': False
}
ctb_para = dict()
ctb_para['reg_params'] = ctb_reg_params
ctb_para['fit_params'] = ctb_fit_params
ctb_para['loss_func' ] = lambda y, pred: np.sqrt(mean_squared_error(y, pred))

def ctb_reg(self, para):
    reg = ctb.CatBoostRegressor(**para['reg_params'])
    reg.fit(x_train, y_train, **para['fit_params'])
    pred = reg.predict(x_test)
    loss = para['loss_func'](y_test, pred)
    return {'loss': loss, 'status': STATUS_OK}

fmin(fn=ctb_reg, space=ctb_para, algo=tpe.suggest, max_evals=100, trials=Trials())
```

and after several minutes I get this:

`{'learning_rate': 4}`

how do I extract the best learning rate? Is it  `np.arange(0.05, 0.31, 0.05)[4]`? Is there a nicer way to extract it?

Comment: Hi, can I ask you what do you use for 'para' argument here? I tried to use your code verbatim since I can't access the Medium article. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```py
from hyperopt import space_eval
print(space_eval(ctb_para, fmin_result))
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/349538) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.